# cylinder class calculations displaying 0.0

Tags: constructor

public class Turner_A03Q1
    {
       public static class Cylinder
       {
        double radius;
        double height;
        double area = (2 * Math.PI * radius * height) + (2 * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2));
         double volume = height * Math.PI * radius * radius;
      public Cylinder(double radius, double height)
     {
         this.radius = radius;
         this.height = height;
     }
      public double getRadius()
     {
         return radius;
     }
     public void setRadius(double r)
     {
         radius = r;
        }
      public double getHeight()
      {
          return height;
     }
     public void setHeight(double h)
     {
         height = h;
     }
     public double getArea()
     {
         return area;
        }
     public double getVolume()
     {
         return volume;
        }
     public String toString()
     {
         return ("Cylinder Area is " + area + " and the volume is " + volume + "."); 
     }
    }
     public static void main (String [] args)
     {
         Cylinder cylinder1 = new Cylinder(5.5, 7.8);

```
     System.out.println(cylinder1);
     cylinder1.setRadius(2.4);
     System.out.println(cylinder1);
     cylinder1.setHeight(10.9);
     System.out.println(cylinder1);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry everyone not sure why it posted my code like that

```
 public class Turner_A03Q1
 {
public static class Cylinder
  {
 double radius;
 double height;
 double area = (2 * Math.PI * radius * height) + (2 * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2));
double volume = height * Math.PI * radius * radius;
 public Cylinder(double radius, double height)
 {
     this.radius = radius;
     this.height = height;
 }
 public double getRadius()
 {
     return radius;
    }
 public void setRadius(double r)
 {
     radius = r;
    }
  public double getHeight()
  {
      return height;
 }
 public void setHeight(double h)
 {
     height = h;
 }
 public double getArea()
 {
     return area;
    }
 public double getVolume()
 {
     return volume;
    }
 public String toString()
 {
     return ("Cylinder Area is " + area + " and the volume is " + volume + "."); 
 }
}
 public static void main (String [] args)
 {
     Cylinder cylinder1 = new Cylinder(5.5, 7.8);

     System.out.println(cylinder1);
     cylinder1.setRadius(2.4);
     System.out.println(cylinder1);
     cylinder1.setHeight(10.9);
     System.out.println(cylinder1);
  }
```

}

Comment: This is the question it keeps returning 0.0 i have asked and people have said the reason but i just dont understand why i really need to see what i am doing wrong here